# Easiest way to rename the extensions on 100 files in a directory in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, rename

I have 100+ files in a directory named ***.php5**.

I would like to rename them all to ***.php**.

Is there a way to do this in **Windows 7**?

Answer (score 7):

In the regular command prompt:

```
ren *.php5 *.php
```

Answer (score 3):

In powershell:

```
 dir *.php5 | ForEach-Object { move $_ $_.Name.TrimEnd('5') }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer) is a fantastic renaming app. It's got a gui and can be run from the command-line. Plus it makes renaming images and mp3s a breeze.

And while you could just use `ren` as Stephen Jennings suggests. You could also bust out some old-school FOR loop fun--again in the regular command prompt.

```
FOR /f %i IN ('dir /b *.php5') DO rename %i %~ni.php
```